# Transfer all blog posts to another wordpress database using mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i would like to get just the blog posts from "blog a" and transfer it to "blog b", blog b has some existing posts in it and i would like to add the posts from a to b using mysql.

edit:
btw, is there any way i can also use the importer to transfer all my uploaded images?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use MySQL; it can get a bit tricky.

Why don't you use the [Wordpress Import feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#WordPress) ?

Comment: its because of the upload limit in php. its only limited to 2mb. my plan was to select all the posts in wp_posts table and export it and import it to my other blog, but it might affect other tables that i dont know.

Comment: Maybe, if you worry about "upload limit", why don't you first export (not all of them, SOME of them : via Tools->Export) from the first blog, and import into the second one? This way, you'll be able to split the total size in several chunks... ;-)

Comment: ok, that's what im planning to do. is there any way to export also the images?

Answer (score 1):

If the permalinks are setup the same such as

```
/%category%/%postname%
```

Then you could just zip up all the image folders from Blog A and reupload these images onto the web server on Blog B and extract into the appropriate folder (wp-content/uploads)

I've had some great success in the past with the WP Import Tool plugin, it did take it's time, but copied roughly 400mb worth of images, posts, categories, pages from a Wordpress.com site to a domain level site.